# Serializar json en wcf

Tags: wcf

Estoy implementando un web service con una relación de *muchos a muchos*, pero el método **GET** me arroja el siguiente error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'No se espera el
>   tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WebApplication3.ViewModel.ActividadesViewModel,
>   Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' con
>   el nombre de contrato de datos
>   'ArrayOfActividadesViewModel:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication3.ViewModel'.
>   Si está usando DataContractSerializer, intente usar
>   DataContractResolver o agregar tipos no conocidos estáticamente a la
>   lista de tipos conocidos (por ejemplo, usando el atributo
>   KnownTypeAttribute o agregándolos a la lista de tipos conocidos que se
>   pasa a DataContractSerializer).'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando un poco me encuentro con que hay que poner el atributo `[KnownType(typeof(Subclase)]` en las entidades pero no logro corregir el error con eso.

Comment: Hola no comprendo si quieres devolver un objeto json en tu servicio o quieres grabar un archivo de texto plano con formato json.